# Assign directly an object to a template in meteor

Tags: meteor, mustache

Is there a way to directly assign an object to a template and let it show his properties ?

A thing like this

```
//Object returned is {totalResults:34,firstName="hoyo"}
Template.myTemplate = function(){
    return Session.get("anObject");
};
```

on this template :

```
<template name="myTemplate">
    <h3>Info results : {{totalResults}}</h3>
        <span>Other things : {{firstName}}</span>
</template>
```

With thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dot notation. But you still need to make a Template helper within the template. Template.mytemplate is reserved for the actual template instance.

Your JS

```
Template.myTemplate.data = function(){
    return Session.get("anObject");
};
```

Your HTML

```
<template name="myTemplate">
    <h3>Info results : {{data.totalResults}}</h3>
        <span>Other things : {{data.firstName}}</span>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I would use the with-block helper:

```js
Template.myTemplate.data = function(){
    return Session.get("anObject");
}
```

```html
<template name="myTemplate">
    {{#with data}}
        <h3>Info results : {{totalResults}}</h3>
        <span>Other things : {{firstName}}</span>
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for this example of the #with block. This helped me refactor my code significantly!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can directly pass a data context to a template:

```
<template name="foo">
  {{> myTemplate data }}
</template>
```

Where you specify

```
Template.foo.data = function(){
    return Session.get("anObject");
};
```